# Downloading blob from oracle database

Tags: php, oracle, codeigniter, blob

I'm trying to transfer blob from oracle database to local filesystem using codeigniter. There are realy a lot of problems with it. First just selecting blob was pain in the ass. Since when I tried like that:

```
 select BLOB from BLOBTABLE where id=820185949471;
```

I get error like that

```
ORA-22992: cannot use LOB locators selected from remote tables
```

Then i tried like that

```
 SELECT (select BLOB from BLOBTABLE where id=820185949471) AS BLOB FROM DUAL;
```

and i get response, which i can var_dump to get that:

```
 object(OCI-Lob)[18]
 public 'descriptor' => resource(35, oci8 descriptor)
```

So I went on google some and get idea that I should do something like that

```
$tmpBlob = $blob->load();
```

But now I get new error saying

```
OCI-Lob::load(): ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

So I finally give up and try to ask good people here!

Comment: Is BLOBTABLE a synonym for a table in a remote database (using a database link)?

Comment: Yes unfortunaly. I don't think this is even possible to be done.